# how can i make my background image fit to phone screen using styled components in react

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my code and i am trying to make my background image fit to my phone screen properly

```
const StyledHero = styled.header`
  min-height: 100vh;


  /* background: url(${defaultImg}); */
  background: url(${props => (props.img ? props.img : defaultImg)});
  background-repeat: space;
  background-position: center;

background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  @media (max-width: 800px) {

 }

`;
```

this is a phone view [phone view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br8jA.png)

this is the regular view [regular view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCuSA.png)

Comment: easier to help if you share working code

Comment: the code works but just doesnt work well on phone view

Answer (score 0):

Try

`background-size: 100%` (this sets the image width to the screen's width and it wont stretch it but gonna repeat it many times until it fill the whole space)

or

`background-size: 100% 100%` (this gonna stretch the image to the width and the height of the screen)